# ParentViewController returns nil

Tags: iphone

I know there are many questions on this, but I don't get it to work.

I present a UITabBarController with the presentModalViewController. However when I try to get title from the navigationItem title attribute in the UINavigationController class that presents the tabcontroller, it returns nil no matter what I do. I have the NSLog in the viewDidLoad method in tabcontroller class.

I also cast the UIViewController which is returned by the self.parentViewController property.
Then I try to access the title through:    NSLog(@"%@", castedViewController.navigationItem.title);

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you talking about two different thing. The first is a `UITabBarController`, the thing you have at the bottom two or more buttons. The second thing is a `UINavigationController` which is on the top of each view presenting a title and a back button.
If you present the tabBar modally then you would not get a back button, you should push it instead. (something like navigationController-pushView can't name it exactly for now).

Anyway try not to call the `navigationItem.title` but instead `navigationBar.topItem.title`